# Storing and retrieving data within the phonegap application (text and images)

Tags: sqlite, cordova, local-storage, phonegap-plugins, html-framework-7

I've been struggling a lot with this for a week and really hope one of you guys can help me with this? Please help me on this, as any of my friends are not working on phonegap.

I'm new to the phonegap and keenly interested to learn. I have designed a app and now I need to add a functionality to it.

Basically my scenario is, I have a list of items(approx. 500) say name,address,city and profile pic as 1 item and similarly 500 itmes are there.
when I open the app on the subscription page I want to populate this list of 500 items in a dropdown or something convinent.
I can see all this 500 items and subscribe to 4-5 items along with Name, address, city and profile pic.

After the subscription, whenever I open my home screen all these 4-5 items should be populated as a List.

Googling has left me quite confused. I want to make sure that I am using the best method for storing data for my users. After a lot of reading articles I founf I can use these :
    1. local Storage 
    2. SQLite

Also I'm using Framework 7 for developing the UI.

Thanks in advance,
Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a PhoneGap based app where I needed to solve for a similar challenge. In my case I have both the local storage and cloud storage:

- Local: SQLite
- Cloud: MongoDB (mLab) on Heroku.

You do want to have the local storage for offline access, and SQLite is a fine choice for this. It is pretty much a standard for native development as well as PhoneGap based development.

There are some limitations (like inability to insert more than 500 records at a time) but this is not likely to be an issue for your use case.

You can use the [built in sqlite PhoneGap plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) or one of the forks available on GitHub if you need some additional flexibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Sorry for replying late I was travelling actually.
I'm using SQLite to solve my current problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not to much option - you using a js, which is simply not designed for storing data or use databases. I recomend you to try
http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/ - this is pretty good wrapper for all of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Sorry for replying late I was travelling actually.